# Connect to bluetooth device without opening a socket

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I've got a background task registered that will handle a (rfcomm) bluetooth connection as soon as my bluetooth device connects. Now, what I want to do is make a "Connect" button, just like the one in the Gadgets app. It should force the device to connect to my bluetooth device without opening a socket, so that the background task can handle it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The BlueTooth should use the StreamSocket and it should use the socket.

```
    async void send(string str)
    {
        StreamSocket socket = await PeerFinder.ConnectAsync(peer);
        DataWriter data_writer=new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        data_writer.WriteString(str);
        await data_writer.StoreAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Then my code crashes: `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`. The reason for this is that while connecting, the rfcomm background task has been started and taken over the connection.